# Is there a way of animating each individual item in a CollectionView in dot net MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Am trying to create a landing page  that contains navigation items, each item has an icon , a description text and an arrow icon.

```
 WalletItems = new List<WalletItem>()
        {
            new WalletItem(ApplicationConstants.Swap, "Transact"),
            new WalletItem(ApplicationConstants.MyInvestments, "View My Investments"),
            new WalletItem(ApplicationConstants.TransactionHistory, "View Transaction History"),

        };
```

the class having this list is a view model.i have set this class as the binding context of my page .

the following  code shows  how i am using data Binding :

```
<ScrollView
                    x:Name="AccountActions"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    VerticalOptions="End">

                    <CollectionView
                        x:Name="WalletItemsCollectionView"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding WalletItems}">
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="10" Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:WalletItem">
                                <Border
                                    Padding="10"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    MinimumHeightRequest="80"
                                    MinimumWidthRequest="300"
                                    Stroke="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                                    StrokeThickness="0">
                                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5" />
                                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                                    <VerticalStackLayout
                                        Padding="0"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                        Spacing="10">
                                        <Button
                                            x:Name="WalletButton"
                                            Background="Red"
                                            Text="hello there " />
                                        <Grid
                                            Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                            Padding="0,10,10,0"
                                            ColumnDefinitions=".8*,.2*">
                                            <HorizontalStackLayout
                                                Grid.Column="0"
                                                Spacing="20"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center">
                                                <Border
                                                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                                    MinimumHeightRequest="50"
                                                    MinimumWidthRequest="50"
                                                    Opacity=".9"
                                                    Stroke="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                                                    StrokeThickness="0">
                                                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                                                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="25" />
                                                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                                                    <Image
                                                        x:Name="HideOrShowPasswordImage"
                                                        HeightRequest="25"
                                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                        Opacity="1"
                                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                        WidthRequest="25">
                                                        <Image.Source>
                                                            <FontImageSource
                                                                FontFamily="Icons"
                                                                Glyph="{Binding IconGlyph}"
                                                                Color="{StaticResource White}" />
                                                        </Image.Source>
                                                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped" />
                                                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    </Image>
                                                </Border>

                                                <Label
                                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource PoppinsSemiBold}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                                                    TextColor="{StaticResource Gray500}"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                            <Image
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                HeightRequest="20"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                WidthRequest="20">
                                                <Image.Source>
                                                    <FontImageSource
                                                        FontFamily="Icons"
                                                        Glyph="{StaticResource ArrowRightOpen}"
                                                        Color="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                                </Image.Source>
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped" />
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>
                                        </Grid>

                                        <!--  Divider  -->
                                        <Border
                                            x:Name="Divider"
                                            Margin="10,0,10,0"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                            Stroke="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                                            StrokeThickness=".52" />

                                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                                </Border>

                            </DataTemplate>

                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>

                </ScrollView>
```

I would like to animate each item  so that when the page appears , each items  behaves as if its smoothly scrolling upwards  at the same time its opacity increases from 0 to 1.

the following is the code i have tried :

```
 public WalletPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new WalletViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Appearing += WalletPage_Appearing;
    }
```

```
private void WalletPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      

        foreach (var item in WalletItemsCollectionView)
        {
            var combinedAnimation = new Animation();

            // Opacity Animation
            var opacityAnimation = new Animation(v => item.Opacity = v, 0, 1);
            combinedAnimation.Add(0, 1, opacityAnimation);

            // Translation Animation
            var translationAnimation = new Animation(v => item.TranslationY = v, -100, 0);
            combinedAnimation.Add(0, 1, translationAnimation);

            combinedAnimation.Commit(item, "CombinedAnimation", 16, 500, Easing.Linear);

        }


    }
```

i get the error :  foreach cannot operate on variables of type "CollectionView" ....

Thank you so much to anyone who will to help me get out of this . Kind Regards.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot iterate the *CollectionView* like that. It's not a collection itself, it hosts a collection of view items that is dynamically created/updated when the associated `ItemsSource` property changes. You'll need to access the child views and iterate through those to animate them. However, there is one important caveat: The `OnAppearing()` method may be called before the *CollectionView* is populated, unless it's done synchronously in the constructor and not asychronously.